Apache NiFi custom processor runtime environment error
I am using NiFi 2.0 that supports python scripts directly from a working directory, after I add my custom processor to the canvas, an error "Processor invalid because initializing runtime environment for the processor" is indicated in each custom processor. I have already installed Java JDK 21, python 3.11 and all the requirements specified in the official documentation. How can I resolve this?
I have already installed Java JDK 21, python 3.11 and all the requirements specified in the official documentation.I changed the python extension parameters in the nifi.properties file.

this is what appears in the app-log:
2024-07-24 10:31:06,608 ERROR [Initialize CreateFlowFile] org.apache.nifi.NiFi An Unknown Error Occurred in Thread VirtualThread[#138,Initialize CreateFlowFile]/runnable@ForkJoinPool-1-worker-2
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to launch Process for Python Processor [CreateFlowFile] Version [0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
at org.apache.nifi.py4j.StandardPythonBridge.getProcessForNextComponent(StandardPythonBridge.java:267)
at org.apache.nifi.py4j.StandardPythonBridge.createProcessorBridge(StandardPythonBridge.java:125)
at org.apache.nifi.py4j.StandardPythonBridge.lambda$createProcessor$7(StandardPythonBridge.java:142)
at org.apache.nifi.python.processor.PythonProcessorProxy.lambda$new$0(PythonProcessorProxy.java:78)
at java.base/java.lang.VirtualThread.run(VirtualThread.java:309)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to create Python Environment ./work/python/extensions/CreateFlowFile/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: process existed with code 1
at org.apache.nifi.py4j.PythonProcess.setupEnvironment(PythonProcess.java:359)
at org.apache.nifi.py4j.PythonProcess.start(PythonProcess.java:129)
at org.apache.nifi.py4j.StandardPythonBridge.getProcessForNextComponent(StandardPythonBridge.java:248)
... 4 common frames omitted
